# Import components from .war file in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm new to `Angular 2`. I want to reuse `Angular` component from `war` file in my `Angular` project. How can I import that component from `war` file to my `Angular` project? Or Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

.war files are just zip files.

1. Unzip the war file
2. Find the component file
3. import it into the project / place it into the project folder